# reducing cycle of redeployment of Shiny Applications in RStudio

Tags: r, deployment, shiny, rstudio, redeploy

Whenever I make changes to Shiny Applications made through RStudio and which is hosted in shiny apps, I have to redeploy it which takes time. How can it this redeployment time be cut short. What automatic functionality or package can be added to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's not a way to reduce the time taken to deploy a package to ShinyApps currently. But we do recommend that you develop and test the package locally before deploying it to ShinyApps. That way you can iterate on your application very quickly by testing locally using the `shiny::runApp()` command then when you're happy with your application, deploy to ShinyApps.io.

Comment: Local testing is a known thing right? Any other suggestions?